# Div adaptable horizontal de tres columnas

Tags: html5, css

Estoy aprendiendo HTML5/CSS3.

Quiero hacer un div horizontal de tres columnas que, si se reduce la ventana o se carga la web en un dispositivo con menos espacio horizontal, se convierta en tres filas (es decir, una columna sobre otra en lugar de al lado).

Ejemplo: http://www.alexa.com/plans

¿Podéis indicarme algún tutorial o la manera de hacerlo? Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

En la hoja de estilos tendrás que definir las propiedades de los div dos veces. Una para cuando el ancho sea menor de uno especificado, y otro para cuando sea mayor.

```
    div div { border: solid;
              width: 30%; 
              height: 400px;
              margin: 1%;
              float: left; }

    @media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
        div div { border: solid;
                  width: 90%; 
                  height: 400px;
                  margin: 5%; }
                }
```

El primero le dará un ancho de un 30% de la pantalla y los alineará cuando el ancho sea superior a 720 píxeles (en este caso), y el segundo le dará un ancho de 90% de la pantalla a cada div, colocándolos uno debajo de otro en caso de que el ancho sea menor.

De todas formas, librerías como Bootstrap te harán el trabajo mucho más fácil, ya que no hay que definir ninguna regla, lo hace solo.

Answer (score 2):

Recomendaria que evalues usar alguna libreria responsive como ser `bootstrap`

[55+ Best Free and Premium CSS Pricing Tables](http://www.utilnow.com/2015/free-pricing-table/)

[3 Column Responsive Layout](http://codepen.io/Cheesetoast/pen/KFAaq)

Veras que hay muchas alernativas de diseño usando template prediseñados de bootstrap, como por ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la imagen es solo uno entre varios quq tienes para elegir.

O puedes crear algo mas custom si es que no quieres todo un template

[Bootstrap 3.0. Simple Pricing](http://www.bootply.com/s2fcu5L2f4)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres hacer se puede lograr por medio de las **[`media` queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries)**:

> Una media query consiste en un tipo de medio y al menos una consulta que limita las hojas de estilo utilizando características del medio como ancho, alto y color. Se entiende como un módulo CSS3 que permite adaptar la representación del contenido a características del dispositivo. Añadido en CSS3, las media queries dejan que la presentación del contenido se adapte a un rango específico de dispositivos de salida sin tener que cambiar el contenido en sí.

Las media queries ejecutan código CSS si se cumplen dos condiciones:

- Tipo de pantalla (opcional)
- Restricción adicionales (opcional) que pueden ser de tamaño, color, resolución, etc.

y su sintaxis es simple:

```
@media [tipo-de-pantalla] [(restricción-adicional)] {

    /* estilos que se aplicarán sólo para esa pantalla si cumple al restricción de tamaño*/

}
```

Un ejemplo usando las media queries sería así:

```css
.columna {
  width:33%;
  float:left;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  
  .columna {
    width:auto;
    float:none;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="columna">Columna1</div>
<div class="columna">Columna2</div>
<div class="columna">Columna3</div>
```

En el código de arriba, se mostrarán 3 columnas (la clase `.columna` tiene ancho 33%) a menos que la página tenga menos de 500 pixels, en ese caso se mostrarán tres líneas (ancho automático y se quita el `float`). Para ver el efecto tendrás que pulsar en el botón de "Pantalla completa" y cambiar el tamaño del navegador.

---

Alternativamente, **si usas una biblioteca como [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)**, esto va a simplificarlo todo (aunque también te obligará a ajustarse a sus tamaños predefinidos). En ese caso puedes usar las clase `.row` y combinarlas con `col-[tamaño]-[columnas]` donde `[columnas]` es un número de 1 al 12, y `tamaño` puede ser:

- xs (`col-xs-*`): extra pequeño, para pantallas de móvil
- sm (`col-sm-*`): pequeño, para tableta
- md (`col-md-*`): medio, para pantallas de ordenador pequeñas/con baja resolución
- lg (`col-lg-*`): grande, para pantallas de ordenador grandes/con alta resolución

Entonces, usando Bootstrap, el código sería más simple:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">Columna 1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">Columna 2</div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">Columna 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Flexbox y media queries, ideal para aprenderlo.

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS) es muy versátil, [aquí](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) tienes una guía completa. Combinado con [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries), puedes pasar de modo fila a columna al cruzar cierto ancho de pantalla. Ya que estas aprendiendo, estos son dos pilares fundamentales del desarrollo web en la actualidad.

Ten en cuenta que Flexbox es una característica relativamente nueva. Según [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex), el 95.74% de los navegadores la soportan.

El ejemplo de abajo, al ser expandido a "[Página Completa]" se ve como columnas en lugar de filas. El limite se ajusta modificando el *media query*.

```css
.container {
  /* Por defecto en modo fila, uno al lado del otro */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;  
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .container {
    /* si es muy angosta, uno debajo del otro */
    flex-flow: column;
  }
}

.rojo {
  background-color: red;
}
.verde {
  background-color: green;
}
.azul {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item rojo"><h1>Tarjeta Roja</h1></div>
  <div class="item verde"><h1>Tarjeta Verde</h1></div>
  <div class="item azul"><h1>Tarjeta Azul</h1></div>
</div>
```